# Why am I getting double content in UITableViewCell after scrolling? (Swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Why am I getting double text in the UITableViewCell after scrolling?

Here's the code for initializing the cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IskanjeCell") as IskanjeShowTableViewCell!

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.setCell(DanKanali, indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell

}

func setCell(danKanali:[DatePS], indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    let vseOddaje = danKanali[indexPath.section].programi[indexPath.row].oddaje
    let program:Program = danKanali[indexPath.section].programi[indexPath.row]
    logoWrapper.frame = CGRectMake(5, CGFloat(5+(vseOddaje.count-1) * 10), logoWrapper.frame.width, logoWrapper.frame.height)
    var sl = program.id.intValue
    sl = sl + 1

    var slik = String(sl)
    mali_logo.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: boundle.pathForResource(slik, ofType: "png")!)

    ime_programa.text = program.ime
    var i = 0
    var base = 15
    if program.oddaje.count == 1
    {
        base = 30 //če je samo 1 show, da postavi na sredino celice
    }
    for oddaja in program.oddaje
    {
        var showWrapper = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, CGFloat(base + i * 45), 300, 40))
        var naslov = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 20))
        var kategorija = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 17, 250, 20))
        naslov.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
        naslov.text = "\(oddaja.ura) - \(oddaja.naslov)"
        naslov.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        kategorija.text = "\(oddaja.kategorija) / \(oddaja.podkategorija)"
        kategorija.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        kategorija.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)

        showWrapper.addSubview(naslov)
        showWrapper.addSubview(kategorija)
        self.contentView.addSubview(showWrapper)
        i++
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting:

[image: Problem]

I already tried with if cell == nil, but this is aperantly not supported any more in swift, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setCell` you are calling `addSubview`, but you are not removing or reusing them when reconfiguring your cell as it scrolls.

**Edit**:
Add to your `IskanjeShowTableViewCell` an `NSMutableArray` of `showWrapper` objects. [Objective-C follows]

```
@interface IskanjeShowTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
// ...
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *showWrappers;
@end

- (void)setCell:(...) {
  // ...

  [self.showWrappers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
  [self.showWrappers removeAllObjects];
  for (id oddaja in program.oddaje) {
    // ...
    [self.showWrappers addObject:showWrapper];
  }
}
```

Comment: Good diagnosis, but incomplete answer.  Full answer is to give the subview a tag.  Create and add the subview conditionally only if its not found via viewWithTag, but then configure the subview unconditionally.

Comment: I don't use `tag`; I much prefer subclassing and making the view relationship explicit. Having the ability to apply a name to a view is much more useful than an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Ok, how can I reuse the cell then, withouth calling the setCell method, if the cell is already set?

Comment: Subclass `UITableViewCell` and add properties for each of your subviews. When you are resetting the cell for reuse, access the subviews through the properties so you won't have to create new ones.

Comment: It's a little difficult for me to help you since your code is not English and I'm not a master at swift. I can explain with Obj-C, though.